# The form argument Drupal\terminal\Form\TerminalCliForm is not a valid form

Tags: forms, blocks, plugins

I've read through other questions regarding the same error message. They all seem to end up being due to typos or the file path. I don't believe that is the case here, but we'll see. I have a working instance of the same code aside from the names, which is all the more confusing.

I enable the module below. Select place its block. And then when I hit the page, receive:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The form argument Drupal\terminal\Form\TerminalCliForm is not a valid form. in Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getFormId() (line 197 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php).
```

I've verified that getFormId receives an empty form_id. I've read that this error message indicates not a bad form in those specific cases but a form file that cannot be found. I'm not certain which is the case, here.

/modules/custom/terminal/src/Form/TerminalCliForm

```
namespace Drupal\terminal\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class TerminalCliForm.
*/
class TerminalCliForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'terminal_cli_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'terminal/terminal';
    $form['canvas'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
    ];
    $form['commandline'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Nothing.
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  }

}
```

/modules/custom/terminal/src/Plugin/Block/TerminalCliBlock - I've tried this with and without the use statement for the form class. In the other module that works correctly, it is present.

```
    namespace Drupal\terminal\Plugin\Block;

    use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
    use Drupal\terminal\Form\TerminalCliForm;

    /**
     * Provides a 'CliBlock' block.
     *
     * @Block(
     *   id = "terminal_cli_block",
     *   admin_label = @Translation("CLI block"),
     *   category = @Translation("Engine block")
     * )
    */

    class TerminalCliBlock extends BlockBase {

     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
     */
     public function build() {

       $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(TerminalCliForm::class);

       return $form;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Have you copy pasted the filenames (and location) or typed it? (I would bet there is a typo in the folder or file names ;))

Comment: web/modules/custom/terminal/src/Form/TerminalCliForm.php and web/modules/custom/terminal/src/Plugin/Block/TerminalCliBlock.php pasted from PhpStorm.

Comment: This file: `/modules/custom/terminal/src/Form/TerminalCliForm` should have the file extension `.php` added to it.

Comment: They both have a .php extension, as pasted above from PhpStorm

Comment: Seems likely PHP can't find the class (`class_exists()` is failing in `FormBuilder::getFormId()`). If the file names are definitely correct try restarting the web server/PHP service - APC can sometimes get confused and need a reset

Comment: That did it @Clive. Clearing cache, no, but stopping and restarting docksal, yes! Please post it as an answer.

Comment: Quite unbeliveable... but indeed, I had the same problem. Cleared the caches multiple times, checked the spelling and paths multiple times. Everything looked just right. I then stopped my Docker containers and restarted them and it worked right away :/ Very weird as I never had to do such a thing to fix a Drupal or PHP issue.

Comment: Same thing just happened to me. Restarting Lando fixed the issue. Very weird.